# How to change the query of a crystal report file (.rpt)?

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

I need to change the query of my crystal report file (.rpt) depending of a filter (where clause). How can i do this (change the where clause of my query)? (In the code behind)

Obs: i'm using crystal report 13, .net framework 4.0 and c#.

Comment: Gonna need a little more detail than that. What are the "filters" and what are you trying to change in the query as a result of them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally speaking, you can add conditions to the WHERE-clause by adding them to the report's record selection formula. For example, if you want records in the Order table that match, say, location 1 and last year then you can do something like:

`string selectFormula = "{Order.LocationID} = 1 AND {Order.Year} = 2011";`

Then add to your report definition via

`crystalReportViewer.SelectionFormula = selectFormula;`

Comment: One last doubt, that i know that doesn't match the question topic, but i saw now, running a few tests with CR. I saw that to every viewer that i open to a specific CR, the CR engine opens a new connection. There is a way to reuse the opened connection? There is a way to manipulate the CR pool?